# How to compute this integral $\int_0^1 x^2 \arctan (e^{-x}) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have tried hard to estimate this definite integral $$I:=\int_0^1 x^2 \arctan(e^{-x}) dx,$$
but all in vain. This exercise is from Page 204, 4.115, of Giaquinta & Modica's Book Mathematical Analysis, Foundations of One Variable. Actually I have tried using substitution $t=arctan(e^{-x})$, or $s=e^{-x}$, and with the help of integration by parts, but can not get the result. Even by using Maple, what I got is just the following: 
$$1/2\,i \left( -2\,{\it polylog} \left( 4,i \right) +2\,{\it polylog}
 \left( 4,-i \right) +{\it polylog} \left( 2,{\frac {i}{e}} \right) 
 \left( \ln  \left( e \right)  \right) ^{2}+2\,{\it polylog} \left( 3,
{\frac {i}{e}} \right) \ln  \left( e \right) +2\,{\it polylog} \left( 
4,{\frac {i}{e}} \right) -{\it polylog} \left( 2,{\frac {-i}{e}}
 \right)  \left( \ln  \left( e \right)  \right) ^{2}-2\,{\it polylog}
 \left( 3,{\frac {-i}{e}} \right) \ln  \left( e \right) -2\,{\it 
polylog} \left( 4,{\frac {-i}{e}} \right)  \right)  \left( \ln 
 \left( e \right)  \right) ^{-3}.
$$

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following [identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html):
$$
    \arctan\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\cosh(t)}
$$
giving the following series expansion:
$$
   \arctan\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4} -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty E_{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
where $E_{n-1}$ stands for [Euler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number). Thus, integrating term-wise:
$$
   \int_0^1 x^2 \arctan(\mathrm{e}^{-x}) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{1}{12} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{E_{n-1}}{n+3} \frac{1}{n!} 
$$
Numerical verification in *Mathematica*:

```
In[30]:= Pi/4 1/3 - 1/2 Sum[EulerE[n - 1]/n! 1/(n + 3), {n, 1, 250}] //
  N[#, 50] &

Out[30]= 0.14856508694081562686677775980253267668127537253127

In[31]:= % - 
 NIntegrate[x^2 ArcTan[Exp[-x]], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 200]

Out[31]= 0.*10^-51
```

Comment: Nice solution. Do you think that a closed form solution does not exist?